# Rails 3 - XML Builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, builder

I'm having an issue with my index.xml.builder file for picture albums; I'm sure it's something simple but it's driving me crazy after not finding a solution in the Builder::XmlMarkup docs. Here is my current view:

```
xml.instruct!
xml.gallery {
@albums.each { |g|
  xml.album(g.name, {:title => g.name, 
                    :description => g.description, 
                    :lgpath => "[PATH]",
                    :tnpath => "[PATH]",
                    :fspath => "[PATH]"})
     g.pictures.each { |p|
      xml.img nil, :src => "#{p.resource_file_name}"
    }
  }
}
```

However, this is producing the following:

```
<gallery>
  <album title="..." description="..." lgpath="..." tnpath="..." fspath="..."></album>
    <img src="17112.jpg"/>
    <img src="17113.jpg"/>
    <img src="17114.jpg"/>
    <img src="17115.jpg"/>
  <album...
```

As you can see, I am unable to get the images nested inside the `</album>` tag. Any ideas how to get that going?

Thanks in advance.

**WRAP-UP (Thanks to iain for putting me on the right path):**

Never underestimate reading the source code, in this case Builder::XmlBase#method_missing. The solution was to not pass in a string for the tag content (g.name). This is the code that I needed:

```
xml.instruct!
xml.gallery do
  @albums.each do |g|
    xml.album(:title => g.name) do 
      g.pictures.each do |p|
        xml.img(:src => p.resource_file_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look again, because Builder doesn't generate invalid XML.

After stubbing out some things (replacing the gallery and pictures with simple arrays), you essentially wrote this code:

```
xml.instruct!
xml.gallery do
  [1, 2, 3].each do |g|
    xml.album g.to_s, :title => g.to_s, :fspath => "[PATH]"
    [4, 5, 6].each do |p|
      xml.img nil, :src => "#{p}.gif"
    end
  end
end
```

Which results in this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<gallery> 
  <album title="1" fspath="[PATH]">1</album> 
  <img src="4.gif"></img> 
  <img src="5.gif"></img> 
  <img src="6.gif"></img> 
  <album title="2" fspath="[PATH]">2</album> 
  <img src="4.gif"></img> 
  <img src="5.gif"></img> 
  <img src="6.gif"></img> 
  <album title="3" fspath="[PATH]">3</album> 
  <img src="4.gif"></img> 
  <img src="5.gif"></img> 
  <img src="6.gif"></img> 
</gallery>
```

You probably want to have the img-tags inside the album tags, but your own nesting is wrong for that. Indenting your code will help you figure it out, and using `do`...`end` blocks instead of curly braces, whenever you use multiple lined blocks helps the structure too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are correct in that I missed the album tag and that, indeed, I want the images nested. I cannot spot the error of my way because I am calling g.pictures within the scope of the gallery block. I'm sure my mistake is mind-numbingly stupid, so I'll keep plugging away...

Comment: call the g.pictures inside a block for album and you should be ready to go. You might want to make the name of the album a tag or an attribute though